# Best Practice for Text and list box input

Tags: vb.net, forms, keyevent

I have a lengthy form containing multiply text boxes and list boxes in order to gather data.
There is a logical sequence to the controls and the tab indexes are set to lead the user through.
My problem is that I loose the plot when I try to control the flow with keydown events - particularly constructing the KeyEventArgs to simulate tab when it is keys.Enter.

Is there a "best practice" algorithm to help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show the code that doesn't work and explain _exactly_ how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question, this is what you should be doing:

```vb
Private Sub TabOnEnterKey(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown,
                                                                       TextBox2.KeyDown,
                                                                       ListBox1.KeyDown,
                                                                       ListBox2.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Select Case e.Modifiers
            Case Keys.None
                'Move forward in the Tab order.
                SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, True, True, True, True)
            Case Keys.Shift
                'Move backward in the Tab order.
                SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, False, True, True, True)
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

As per the comment, setting `e.SuppressKeyPress` to `True` will prevent a sound being played when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed in a single-line `TextBox`. There are various ways the code could be structured, keeping in mind that you only want to do it if you actually call `SelectNextControl`. You could just add the same code twice to what I already posted:

```vb
Private Sub TabOnEnterKey(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown,
                                                                       TextBox2.KeyDown,
                                                                       ListBox1.KeyDown,
                                                                       ListBox2.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Select Case e.Modifiers
            Case Keys.None
                'Move forward in the Tab order.
                SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, True, True, True, True)

                'Prevent sound playing in single-line TextBoxes.
                e.SuppressKeyPress = True
            Case Keys.Shift
                'Move backward in the Tab order.
                SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, False, True, True, True)

                'Prevent sound playing in single-line TextBoxes.
                e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

or you might do this:

```vb
Private Sub TabOnEnterKey(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown,
                                                                       TextBox2.KeyDown,
                                                                       ListBox1.KeyDown,
                                                                       ListBox2.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim forward As Boolean? = Nothing

        Select Case e.Modifiers
            Case Keys.None
                forward = True
            Case Keys.Shift
                forward = False
        End Select

        If forward.HasValue Then
            'Move following the Tab order.
            SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, forward.Value, True, True, True)

            'Prevent sound playing in single-line TextBoxes.
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to add `e.SuppressKeyPress = True` to get rid of the "beep" sound.